# hibernate relationship

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a table model like below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="RULEADMIN_QUESTIONNAIRE")
public class Questionnaire {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "QUESTID")
    private long questionID;

    @Column(name = "QUESTION")
    private String question;

    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "QUESTORDER")
    private long questionOrder;

    @Column(name = "QUESTCATEGORYID")
    private long questionCatgoryID;

    @Column(name = "QUESTREFERENCESTRING")
    private String questionReferenceString;

    @Column(name = "ACTIVEFLAG")
    private long activeFlag;

    @Column(name = "LASTMODUSERID")
    private long lastModifiedUserID;

    @Column(name = "LASTMODDATE")
    private Date lastModifiedDate;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="QUESTID")
    @Transient
    private List<QuestionAnswerOption> questionAnswerOptions;

        public Questionnaire() {
    }
       .....list of setters and getters
}
```

Here `QUESTID` and `QUESTORDER` will have the same value, `QUESTID` will get generated automatically. But I want the same value for `QUESTORDER` also, because both will have the same value. I have tried by annotating `@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)` but it is not getting the value. How can I get the `QUESTID` to `QUESTORDER` also?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is anything more to the question, but in your case why can't you use just QUESTID itself? what is the need for QUESTORDER?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't make much sense, if there is a compelling reason (some dependent legacy code?) to have two fields that are identical I would do it like this:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "QUESTID")
private long questionID;

public long getQuestionId(){
  return this.questionID;
};

public long getQuestionOrder(){
  return getQuestionID();
};
```